# Windows 8 start screen slow on battery

Tags: windows-8

I have Windows 8 and when it's on battery the start screen seems to be "slower" and "laggy" than when it's plugged in.
I've messed around with the Power Options but still no clue

Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: The first thing to do would be to read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq  StackOverflow is for programming questions.  You will have better luck over at SuperUser.com.  Also, most machines lower the clock speed when unplugged to save power.  Check your BIOS power settings, if available on your device.  Windows can/will override these though, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU speed will automatically be lowered when it is not on AC. You could change power settings to be on "Desktop" mode or similar when running on battery.

Go to the desktop in Win8, then navigate yourself to Control Panel\System and Security\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings. Then click on Edit Plan Settings and Change advanced power settings. It should be under Processor power management.